# Add rows to table even if not in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure how to title this, so I apologize if it's misleading or not understandable.
What I have is an array, that array will have 1-4 arrays within it. I need a HTML table to output 4 columns, so even if the array only has one array in it, it still needs to output for columns. The issue I am hitting is that the columns need to match up. Inside of the arrays there is a key called 'Deductible' and that key matches up with the HTML table's columns. The Array, PHP, current HTML output and wanted HTML output are all below and a link to PasteBin in case this post doesn't display it all correctly.

```
// OUTPUT OF $estimateOutput

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'AdminCode' => 'NASC',
    'AdminName' => 
    array (
    ),
    'NewUsed' => 'Used',
    'CoverageCode' => 'NCGUGOLD',
    'CoverageName' => 'GOLD USED COMPONENT 1-10',
    'GenericCoverage' => 
    array (
    ),
    'Term' => '24/24',
    'TermInMonths' => '24',
    'TermInMilesKM' => '24000',
    'Deductible' => '100',
    'RetailCost' => '1377.0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'AdminCode' => 'NASC',
    'AdminName' => 
    array (
    ),
    'NewUsed' => 'Used',
    'CoverageCode' => 'NCGUGOLD',
    'CoverageName' => 'GOLD USED COMPONENT 1-10',
    'GenericCoverage' => 
    array (
    ),
    'Term' => '24/24',
    'TermInMonths' => '24',
    'TermInMilesKM' => '24000',
    'Deductible' => '50',
    'RetailCost' => '1462.0',
  ),
)


$estimateOutput .= '<tr class="month-section"><td colspan="5"><strong>'.$term_length.' Months</strong></td></tr>';
if($rateEstimate != ""){
  foreach($rateEstimate as $rate) {
    $ratesByMiles[$rate["TermInMilesKM"]][] = $rate;
  }
  foreach($rateEstimate as $key=>$value){
    if($TermInMilesKM != $value['TermInMilesKM']){
      $estimateOutput .= '<tr>';
      $estimateOutput .= '<td>'.number_format($value['TermInMilesKM']).'</td>';

      foreach($ratesByMiles[$value['TermInMilesKM']] as $newval){
        $estimateOutput .= '<td>';
        $estimateOutput .= '<a href="#" rel="'.$newval['CoverageCode'].'::'.$newval['Term'].'::'.$newval['Deductible'].'::'.$newval['RetailCost'].'">$';
        $estimateOutput .= number_format($newval['RetailCost']);
        $estimateOutput .= '</a>';
        $estimateOutput .= '</td>';
      }
      $estimateOutput .= '</tr>';
      $TermInMilesKM = $value['TermInMilesKM'];
    }
  }
} else {
  $estimateOutput .= '<tr><td colspan="5">Not Available</td></tr>';
}
echo $estimateOutput;



// CURRENTLY OUTPUTTING
<tr class="month-section" style="display: table-row;">
  <td colspan="5"><strong>24 Months</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
  <td>24,000</td>
  <td><a rel="NCGUGOLD::24/24::50::1462.0" href="#">$1,462</a></td>
  <td><a rel="NCGUGOLD::24/24::100::1377.0" href="#">$1,377</a></td>
</tr>



// NEED IT TO OUTPUT

<tr class="month-section" style="display: table-row;">
  <td colspan="5"><strong>24 Months</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
  <td>24,000</td>
  <td>--</td> // If $newval['Deductible'] == 0 this should show data, otherwise --
  <td><a rel="NCGUGOLD::24/24::50::1462.0" href="#">$1,462</a></td> // If $newval['Deductible'] == 50 this should show data, otherwise --
  <td><a rel="NCGUGOLD::24/24::100::1377.0" href="#">$1,377</a></td> // If $newval['Deductible'] == 100 this should show data, otherwise --
  <td>--</td> // If $newval['Deductible'] == 200 this should show data, otherwise --
</tr>
```

http://pastebin.com/y41MA8VZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always loop four times, then find the correct array to print:

```
$deductable_values = array(0, 50, 100, 200);
foreach ($deductable_values as $deductable_value) {
    $data = find_deductible_array($estimateOutput, $deductable_value);
    // output a row using $data, which may be null.
}

function find_deductible_array($estimateOutput, $value) {
    foreach ($estimateOutput as $row) {
        if ($row['deductible'] == $value) {
            return $row;
        }
     }
     // not found
     return null;
}
```

Comment: With a bit of tweaking that did exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! Only 5 hours wasted running in circles...